# Automatic "<!--: spam" tag from Apache?

Tags: python, html, apache, spam

i have a realy strange problem.
I try to display a relativly huge table (ca. 100 rows) from a database with a python script.
It worked perfectly on my computer via XAMPP but when i test in on my webserver only 8 rows will be displayed and below the following is added autmaticly:

```
<!--: spam
Content-Type: text/html

<body bgcolor="#f0f0f8"><font color="#f0f0f8" size="-5"> -->
<body bgcolor="#f0f0f8"><font color="#f0f0f8" size="-5"> --> -->
</font> </font> </font> </script> </object> </blockquote> </pre>
</table> </table> </table> </table> </table> </font> </font> </font>
```

Why it wont work?

Comment: ask your hosting company ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stuff you're looking at there is part of the output of the Python [`cgitb`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgitb.html) (CGI traceback) module. The fact that you're seeing it indicates that your script is probably throwing an exception - time to start debugging!

Comment: Ok, thanks for that Information, but why it work with XAMPP? =(

Comment: @knusperwurst: maybe because the exception is not thrown under XAMPP?